# How to handle nesting and organizing your translation keys using i18next and react-i18next? and other best practices questions

Tags: reactjs, localization, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I have a couple of questions about best practices and the workflow when working with i18n
I am currently using `react-i18next`
I am defining the keys directly with default values in the components and then extracting them using `babel-plugin-i18next-extract`

**Example**

```
    <I18nText
        ns="meeting"
        i18nKey="meeting-invitation.videoConferenceLink"
        defaults="You can join the video conference call for {{meeting.name}} when it starts via: <br /> <0>{{meeting.videoConference.link}}</0>"
        components={[
            <a
                href={meeting.videoConference.link}
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
                {meeting.videoConference.link}
            </a>,
        ]}
        values={{ meeting }}
    />
```

**Note:** `I18nText`  is a custom component wrapping `Trans` component

## **Questions:**

1️⃣ **Should I put keywords that I use a lot across the app into their own key? if so, how do I handle pluralization, formatting and using context at the same time?**

let's say that I use the keywords `meeting` and `action` across the app and I have a sentence like this

```
0 meetings, 0 actions         => You have no scheduled meetings and no actions deadlines so far to prepare for.
1 meeting, 1 action           => You have 1 scheduled meeting and 1 action deadline so far to prepare for.
2-inf meetings, 2-inf actions => You have (2-inf) scheduled meetings and (2-inf) action deadlines so far to prepare for.
```

`meetings` and `actions` can have a different count, I am aware that I can use nesting and that I pass count to each nested key like this

```
"key": "You have $t(glossary:scheduledMeetingWithCount, {\"count\": {{meetingCount}}}) and $t(glossary:actionDeadlinesWithCount, {\"count\": {{actionCount}}}) so far to prepare for."
```

But won't the translators get confused with all the nesting and passing count? and the `scheduledMeetingWithCount` and the `actionDeadlinesWithCount` keys, to what namespace should they be in? `glossary`? each in their own related namespace as in `meeting` and `action` namespaces?
and how should there definition look like

```
"scheduledMeetingWithCount": "1 scheduled meeting",
"scheduledMeetingWithCount_plural": "{{count}} scheduled meeting",
"scheduledMeetingWithCount_0": "no scheduled meetings"  // doesn't i18next not support `_0` for `en`?
```

and won't that make the keys `meeting` and `action`  be needed to be translated multiple times? as when it's defined alone `meeting` , its plural form `meetings`, when there is a count `no meetings`, `1 meeting` and `(2-inf) meeting`, and when I need to add `scheduled` before the meeting name as in `1 scheduled meeting`, `{{count}} scheduled meetings` and `no scheduled meetings`? Am I going to do this for each keyword I use across the system?

2️⃣ **How can I format nested keys?**

Let's say I have a key with value `Meetings are scheduled for next week`
and I have a key for `meeting_plural` wtih the value `meetings`, but it's lowercase but I have a format function `titleCase`
So I wanted to use something like `{{$t(glossary:meeting_plural), titleCase}} are scheduled for next week`
but that results in `meeting_plural), titleCase}} are scheduled for next week`
I've also tried

```
t('{{meeting, titleCase}} are scheduled for next week', {meeting: '$t(glossary:meeting_plural)'})
```

but that results in `$T(Glossary:Meeting_Plural) are scheduled for next week`
so I ended up using

```
t('{{meeting, titleCase}} are scheduled for next week', { meeting: t('glossary:meeting_plural') })
```

which worked
but is that best practice, should I just leave the translator to translate meetings again? should I add another key for when the "meetings" is title-cased?

3️⃣ **How to handle variations in values, should I use context or add a key for every variation? if I use context how do I extract each context  that is required?**

I have a sentence that changes based on whether the passed action has the property `dueDate` or not
when `dueDate` exists it shows this

```
Looks like you have a new action to complete: <strong>{{ action.title }}</strong> assigned by <strong> {{ action.creator.name }} </strong> and to be completed before <strong>{{ action.dueDate, dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY }}</strong>.
```

if `dueDate` doesn't exist it shows

```
Looks like you have a new action to complete: <strong>{{ action.title }}</strong> assigned by <strong> {{ action.creator.name }} </strong>.
```

how should I handle this case? should they be separated in their own keys?
I've tried using context like this

```
t('action:action-assigned.content', {
  context: action.dueDate && 'dated'
})
```

and keys to `action.json` as

```
"action-assigned.content": "Looks like you have a new action to complete: <strong>{{ action.title }}</strong> assigned by <strong> {{ action.creator.name }} </strong>.",
"action-assigned.content_dated": "Looks like you have a new action to complete: <strong>{{ action.title }}</strong> assigned by <strong> {{ action.creator.name }} </strong> and to be completed before <strong>{{ action.dueDate, dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY }}</strong>."
```

is that the right use of context? I had to add these keys manually, not by the extraction tool and had to turn off `discardOldKeys` because it was removing the key with `_dated`

4️⃣ **How do I organize my common keys?**

do I throw anything that I'll use across the system in the `common` namespace and is it okay if I named the key with its value? or would it better to give them a specific key

5️⃣ **Should I abstract values that are similar but have different nouns?**

I have the values `View action`, `View project`, `View meeting`, ...etc. should I make a key with the value `View {{item}}` and pass the `key` for the noun that I want to use or should I just make each value in it's key?

6️⃣ **Is there a TMS that support i18next-intervalPlural-postProcessor?**

7️⃣ **Should I switch to using I18next-icu?**

I found `ICU` to handle pluralization better than `i18next` default format because in `en` I can add a specific condition to `0` instead of being limited to `key` and `key_plural`
and `ICU` also has `select` which is like a switch statement which solves some of the issues that I have, Why doesn't `i18next` have something like `select`? is `context` supposed to handle the use-case that `select` handles?

8️⃣ **Does anyone has any personal recommendation for a TMS that they used before and liked?**

I want one that supports `i18next` features well, I've looked into locize but found their pricing hard to predict I would rather have something with a fixed price

9️⃣ **Is there is a resource that I can learn best-practices and learn how to scale i18n?**

I've searched for i18n resources but found the community to be a little lacking in in-depth guidance or an end-to-end workflow guide, I've mostly been trying things by trial and error but am not sure if I will be facing a roadblock or have growing pains with the current implementation am using